# How to serve up dynamic content via django and php on same domain?

Tags: php, python, django, apache

I just finished rewriting a significant portion of my web site using python's django, but I also have some legacy code in php that I haven't finished migrating over yet. Is it possible to get these two working on the same domain and if so, how do I go about doing it?

I'm running this site on a virtual Ubuntu instance and serving content up via apache. I'm also using mod_wsgi to hook into the python content.

One simplification is that the whole site, except for one sub-directory, runs off python. Let's say for arguments sake that my php code is at http://www.mysite.com/myphpapp/.

Comment: It depends a bit on how your django instance is deployed (mod_wsgi, mod_python, fast_cgi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you have to configure apache to use the default handler for the path hosting your legacy code, usually adding a `<directory>` or `<location>` section to your apache site config.

Something like:

```
<Location "/legacy">
    SetHandler None
</Location>
```