# How to run two webapplication in a single domain? Is that possible?

Tags: php, django, apache

I have a php application configured in apache server that serves api in www.example.com/api1, now i want to run my django app in the same domain but with different route like www.example.com/api2. Is that possible? please give your valuable solutions and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the Django app to serve all URLs under a certain base path (in your main `urls.py`).

You also have to configure your apache server to forward request for that base path to the Django app.
See [How to serve up dynamic content via django and php on same domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954467/how-to-serve-up-dynamic-content-via-django-and-php-on-same-domain?rq=1)

Don't forget to configure `settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS` and SITE (the latter in the Admin UI under "Sites").

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts

---

NOTE:

Make sure you never use hard coded URLs in any of your code except in the `urls.py` files (as a general rule for Django apps). Always use

- `reverse()`, `reverse_lazy()` in the Django code,
- implement `get_absolute_url()` on your models (using `reverse()`),
- `static` (or: `staticfiles`) in the templates.

If you need the complete URL (for Facebook back links e.g.) use `request.build_absolute_uri()`.

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible. I imagine your django app will listen for requests on a certain port, usually that would be port 80, but if I understand correctly, apache is already running on port 80.

So what you have to do is configure your django app to listen for requests on a different port number (8080 for example) and make a route in apache (htaccess) that forwards all requests to www.example.com/api2 to the port number where your django app is running.

Something along these lines in your htaccess should work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /api2
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ example.com:8080/$1 [NC,L]
```